# What HTML5 tags should be used for side logo and navigation?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I'm working in a layout similar to [this](http://www.hundertgrad.de/), with the difference that the logo will be on top of the navigation menu.

This will be the disposition of elements:
[Layout http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27937302/layout.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27937302/layout.png)

I think this should be really simple, but i can't get myself to know for sure which tags should i use for the two main areas of the layout `sidebar` and `content`.

Should the whole left sidebar (including logo and main navigation) be inside a `<header>` tag? `<aside>` a simple `<div>` with `<header>` and `<nav>` inside?

What about the content side? it might have blog posts, portfolio entries, static pages, etc.

Consider that the whole `content` area will have to be dinamically added to the main template.
Also, the `sidebar` has a big image for textured background and it has to fit all height browsers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<nav>` should contain the navigation, `<footer>` should contain the footer, and `<header>` should contain the logo, and possibly also the category links. However, you should then selectively set `position: fixed`, something like this:

```css
#logo, nav, #side-of-footer {
    position: fixed;
}
```

The `#side-of-footer` part could be lots of things depending on the actual final stylesheet, how you want things to look, and how that footer part is currently marked up (in your design, the left side appears to be separate from both the footer and navigation though there is no reason for that).

Comment: Thank you for your time, but, the logo and the top of the content can't be together, logo will be fixed and the content will be scrollable. But all that `sidebar` has to be 100% height. I Updated the question with some other details.

Comment: @ramono: That's why you have `#logo`. `position: fixed` items are completely removed from the document flow, meaning that even if they share a container with something else that can't remain in place while scrolling, that's fine. They just pop out. Pretty convenient :)

Comment: I understand that, but what about the other considerations?

Comment: @ramono: What other considerations?

Comment: The image background for that `sidebar`, the template separation.

Comment: @ramono: Use `background-position` to adjust for size.

Comment: And the background will be in which element?

Comment: @ramono: All of them. Use the same background image, but position it to compensate.

Comment: I was holding myself against doind something like that for no reason, I guess I need to open my mind, :) Thank you.